# Solution of an equation, $x(\log\log9-\log\log x)=\log8$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to find the solution of this equation  analytically $x(\ln(\ln(9))−\ln(\ln(x)))=ln(8)$

Note:- I already know that the solution if this equality is 3, but I don't know how to find it analytical ( not just graph or wolfram alpha ).

Answer (score 1):

The first derivative of $x( \ln(\ln (9))- \ln(\ln(x)))-\ln(8)$ is always negative so the function is always decreasing. Thus, there is only one real root.

Now simplifying from logarithm rules gives $\ln(\ln(9)/\ln(x)) = \ln(8^{1/x})$ and since the function is monotonically increasing, $\ln(9) = 8^{1/x}\ln(x)$ and agian, $9 = x^{8^{1/x}}$. Now the answer of $3$ seems easy to guess. Can we apply the lambert W function here?

Comment: I am not sure how can I use Lamber W function in this case. I mean its not clear its like Lambert W function (IMO). thanks

Comment: No the Lambert W function cannot be used here.

Answer (score 1):

I would have solved this equation this way:

$$
x(\log\log9 -\log\log x) = 3(\log2)
$$

The equation is solved if:

$$
x = 3   
$$
and

$$
 \log\log9 -\log\log 3 = \log2
$$
Simplyfing, you will have $$\log(2\log3/\log3) = \log2 $$
Since this identity is proved, you can assume $$ x = 3 $$

Comment: This only shows that $x=3$ is a solution, not that it's the only one.

Comment: Yep, I'm sorry. I had to add the part to check how many solutions thru the first derivative just like Sandeep said! Pardon! :)

Comment: thanks for answering... but we need to solve this analytically... as I said in the question " I already know that the solution if this equality is 3" .. thanks